# Is there a Tensorflow or Keras equivalent to fastai's interp.plot_top_losses?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction, fast-ai

Is there a Tensorflow or Keras equivalent to fastai's interp.plot_top_losses? If not, how can I manually obtain the predictions with the greatest loss?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is ktrain! Comes with learning rate finder, learning rate schedules, ready to used per-trained models and many more features inspired by fastai.

https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain